# How can I perform a sub-filter using JsonPath?

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I've [read the documentation](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/), and I can't figure out how I perform a sub-filter using JsonPath. Here's an example...

Given the following JSON, how do I retrieve a list of people with an address in `Sydney`?

I've tried variations of `$.people[?(@.addresses[*].city=="Sydney")]` to no avail. e.g.

- `$.people[?(@.addresses[*].city=="Sydney")]`
- `$.people[?(@.addresses.city=="Sydney")]`
- `$.people[?(@..city=="Sydney")]`

#### JSON

```
{
    "people": [{
            "name": "George",
            "addresses": [{
                "city": "Sydney"
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "Jane",
            "addresses": [{
                "city": "Brisbane"
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "Fred",
            "addresses": [{
                    "city": "Perth"
                },
                {
                    "city": "Sydney"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Preferred Output

```
{
    "people": [{
            "name": "George",
            "addresses": [{
                "city": "Sydney"
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "Fred",
            "addresses": [{
                    "city": "Perth"
                },
                {
                    "city": "Sydney"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using the following Java library: `com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.2.0`

I'm using http://jsonpath.com/ to test my jsonpath in the browser (maybe that's the problem?).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `@.addresses[*].city` is a collection. It is not ANY city of the person and it is not ONLY(each) city of the person.

If you are looking for persons with some addresses in Sydney the query should be:

`"$.people[?(\"Sydney\" in @.addresses[*].city)]"`

Example:

```
String filter = "$.people[?(\"Sydney\" in @.addresses[*].city)]";
ReadContext ctx = JsonPath.parse(json);
List<Map<String, Object>> rez = ctx.read(filter, List.class);
```

If you are looking for persons with all addresses in Sydney I do not know correct query. It is possible to use Predicate, but it is very complicated code.

Just for information:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> rez = JsonPath.parse(json).read(
                "$.people[?]",
                List.class,
                new Predicate() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(PredicateContext ctx) {
                Map<String, Object> map = ctx.item(Map.class);
                ReadContext readContext = JsonPath.parse(JSONObject.toJSONString(map));
                List<String> allAddresses = readContext.read("$.addresses[*].city");
                List<String> sydneyAddresses = readContext.read("$.addresses[?(@.city=='Sydney')].city");
                return allAddresses.size() == sydneyAddresses.size();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a filter

```
String jsonData = "{
    "people": [{
            "name": "George",
            "addresses": [{
                "city": "Sydney"
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "Jane",
            "addresses": [{
                "city": "Brisbane"
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "Fred",
            "addresses": [{
                    "city": "Perth"
                },
                {
                    "city": "Sydney"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}"
Filter expensiveFilter = Filter.filter(Criteria.where(['people'][*]['address']['city'].eq("Sydney"));
```

Now you can add this in your JsonPath

```
String peoples = JsonPath.parse(jsonData).read("$['people'][?]", expensiveFilter).toString();
```